# dompdf no line height. Same code, different enviroment

Tags: dompdf

I am having an issue with `DOMPDF`. My code should be fine and I can post if you really want to see it. I dynamically create an HTML page into a cache and then pass it to create the PDF.

I have some REAL BASIC CSS and even was able to use custom font when on LAMP. But even running it with stock fonts, forcing crazy line height in CSS and just about everything else I can think of. I am getting the same smushed text results when on my external linux server.

I have fought with this for days and have googled until my fingers have bled.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

[WAMP/LAMP side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkVMD.jpg)

Comment: I failed to mention I am using the latest ver 0.7 of DOMPDF and PHP version is 5.5.36.  I get no errors when running

Comment: I had to move to a different server,  When I installed on a almost identical 5.5.36 server with the same company it all of the sudden works????  I am happy about that but not happy about knowing why.

Comment: When setting up the initial server did you copy dompdf from another location? This looks like it could be a font metrics issue, which typically rears its ugly head because dompdf is looking in the wrong location for the font metrics files.

Comment: I have not solved this issue but it's no longer a problem for me.  I had that problem on a server the customer no longer needs the site there.  I have since placed the same software in 5 other locations and it works just fine.  Still a mystery but obviously server based issue that is the exception and not the norm.